# hadoop -libjars and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

please help, I'm stuck.
Here is my code to run job.

```
hadoop jar mrjob.jar ru.package.Main -files hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/metadata.csv -libjars hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/opencsv.jar,hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/gson.jar,hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/my-utils.jar /MyCatalog/http_requests.seq-r-00000 /MyCatalog/output/result_file
```

I do get these WARNs:

```
12/10/26 18:35:50 WARN util.GenericOptionsParser: The libjars file hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/opencsv.jar is not on the local filesystem. Ignoring.
12/10/26 18:35:50 WARN util.GenericOptionsParser: The libjars file hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/gson.jar is not on the local filesystem. Ignoring.
12/10/26 18:35:50 WARN util.GenericOptionsParser: The libjars file hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/MyCatalog/jars/my-utils.jar is not on the local filesystem. Ignoring.
```

Then: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**
on line in Main class where I try to instantiate class from jar named my-utils.jar

1. All these jars are in hfds (I see them through file browser)
2. my-utils.jar does contain class which is a reason for **NoClassDefFoundError**

What do I do wrong?

**UPD:**
I'm inspecting sourcecode of **GenericOptionsParser**:

```
/**
   * If libjars are set in the conf, parse the libjars.
   * @param conf
   * @return libjar urls
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static URL[] getLibJars(Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    String jars = conf.get("tmpjars");
    if(jars==null) {
      return null;
    }
    String[] files = jars.split(",");
    List<URL> cp = new ArrayList<URL>();
    for (String file : files) {
      Path tmp = new Path(file);
      if (tmp.getFileSystem(conf).equals(FileSystem.getLocal(conf))) {
        cp.add(FileSystem.getLocal(conf).pathToFile(tmp).toURI().toURL());
      } else {
        LOG.warn("The libjars file " + tmp + " is not on the local " +
          "filesystem. Ignoring.");
      }
    }
    return cp.toArray(new URL[0]);
  }
```

So:
1. no spaces between comma
2. still don't get it... I've tried to point to: local file system, hdfs file system, result is the same. Seems like class is not added...

Comment: There is also detailed answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890087/problem-with-libjars-in-hadoop

Answer (score 4):

Problem is solved. correct invocation is:

```
hadoop jar my-job.jar ru.package.Main -files /home/cloudera/uploaded_jars/metadata.csv -libjars /home/cloudera/uploaded_jars/opencsv.jar,/home/cloudera/uploaded_jars/gson.jar,/home/cloudera/uploaded_jars/url-raiting-utils.jar /MyCatalog/http_requests.seq-r-00000 /MyCatalog/output/scoring_result
```

where

> /MyCatalog

is hdfs path,

> /home/cloudera/uploaded_jars/

is local fs path
**The problem was in job jar.**
Previously I did try to run job using simple jar *with only three classes: Mapper, Reducer, Main class*.
Now I did provide other one generated by maven (it generates two of them)
**The second job jar contains all dependency libs**. in side it. Structure looks like:
*my-job.jar*

-*lib*

--*aopalliance-1.0.jar asm-3.2.jar avro-1.5.4.jar ... commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar ... zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.0.0.jar*

There are 76 jars inside lib folder.

It works but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Just because they are on HDFS, doesn't mean that they are in the classpath of the job you are running.

If you really just want to fix this problem, I would use maven to build a "fat jar" which contains all your dependencies in a single jar. You can do this using the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

But, looking at your command, it looks wrong. I think you might have better luck using the "job" command with -libjars, [described here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/commands_manual.html#jar). I'm not sure that you can specify external jars using the "hadoop jar" command.

Comment: I can't agree with you right now. http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/ it worked before 100%. Then I statred to refactor and... Or I broke someting or there is a bug in Cloudera 4

Comment: and: From 0.19, the jars added using -libjars are available on the client 
classpath also, fixed by HADOOP-3570.

Comment: this error almost always happens when the jars are present at compile time, and then not present at runtime. it is almost definitely a classpath issue

Comment: I do understand it. I did print to console Configuration object in MR-JOB Main class. These jars are passed via arguments. I do see them locally and in HDFS. Of course I do miss someting. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your mrjob.jar determines the jars needed for your Hadoop client job. Either you provide a fat jar or include all your jars under HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

On the other hand, -libjars sets the additional jars needed for the Map and Reduce tasks.

Read this http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/