# hadoop jar error while copying data from mongoDB to hdfs

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, jar

I am trying to copy collection from mongodb to hadoop using HadoopMongodb connector
using the code below :
package hdfs;

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.bson.*;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.*;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.util.*;

public class ImportWeblogsFromMongo {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ImportWeblogsFromMongo.class);

    public static class ReadWeblogsFromMongo extends Mapper<Object, BSONObject, Text, Text> {
        public void map(Object key, BSONObject value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key);
            System.out.println("Value: " + value);
            String md5 = value.get("md5").toString();
            String url = value.get("url").toString();
            String date = value.get("date").toString();
            String time = value.get("time").toString();
            String ip = value.get("ip").toString();
            String output = "\t" + url + "\t" + date + "\t" + time + "\t" + ip;
            context.write(new Text(md5), new Text(output));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(conf,"mongodb://localhost:27017/clusterdb.fish");
        MongoConfigUtil.setCreateInputSplits(conf, false);
        System.out.println("Configuration: " + conf);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        final Job job = new Job(conf, "Mongo Import");
        Path out = new Path("/home/mongo_import");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
        job.setJarByClass(ImportWeblogsFromMongo.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ReadWeblogsFromMongo.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(MongoInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
    }
```

1. After exporting the Jar file named `importmongo.jar`
 2. I tried to execute this command `hadoop jar /home/yass/importmongo.jar hdfs.ImportWeblogsFromMongo` but i got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/hadoop/util/MongoConfigUtil
    at hdfs.ImportWeblogsFromMongo.main(ImportWeblogsFromMongo.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

**NB**:clustedb is the database name and fish its collection
and hdfs.ImportWeblogsFromMongo  is package.class

Any suggestions please

Comment: Did you try `hadoop jar /home/yass/importmongo.jar -libjars HADOOP_MONGODB_JAR hdfs.ImportWeblogsFromMongo`?

Comment: yes and i got an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -libjars

Comment: Sorry, I meant `hadoop jar /home/yass/importmongo.jar hdfs.ImportWeblogsFromMongo -libjars HADOOP_MONGODB_JAR `.  You can see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095402/hadoop-libjars-and-classnotfoundexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095402/hadoop-libjars-and-classnotfoundexception) or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890087/problem-with-libjars-in-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890087/problem-with-libjars-in-hadoop) for the right syntax for using -libjars.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't resolve the issue this way but i found solution using `Mongodump` by copying the file to `Hdfs` ,the lines below it may help someone to get the job done

```
   mongodump  --db clusterdb --collection CollectionName

   bsondump file.bson > file.json

   hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /path/to/file/fish.json mongo
```