# MapReduce: Passing external jar files using libjars option does not work

Tags: hadoop

My map reduce program needs external jar files.  I am using the
"-libjars" option to provide those external jar files -

I used Tool, Configured and ToolRunner Utilities provided by hadoop.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
         int res = ToolRunner.run(newConfiguration(), new MapReduce(),args);
         System.exit(res);
  }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throwsException {
         // Configuration processed by ToolRunner
   Configuration conf = getConf();
   Job job = new Job (conf, "MapReduce");
   ....
   }
```

When I tried to run the job -

```
$ Hadoop jar myjob.jar jobClassName -libjars external.jar
```

It threw the following exception.

> 12/11/21 16:26:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201211211620_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED Error:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder

I have been trying to resolve it for a while. Nothing seems to work so far. I am using CDH 4.1.1.

Comment: I found this question while having the same problem. If I figure it out I'll post, please do the same if you find the exact resolution first.

Comment: Check the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890087/problem-with-libjars-in-hadoop

Answer (score 1):

It seems cannot find JodaTime. Open `/etc/hbase/hbase-env.sh` and add your extra jar to `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="<extra_entries>:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"
```

Another, less efficient and sometimes not possible, idea is to copy your requited jar to `/usr/share/hadoop/lib`.

Comment: I tried HADOOP_CLASSPATH as well. it doesn't work. Copying files at all nodes would not be practical. "-libjars" should copy those files to all nodes. Does "-libjars" work for you?

Comment: So far I never did it with -libjars, I'm using a single node so I just copied the required extra jars to lib/ folder (not the best thing because of what you commented). Another way, if you can build the code, is to build a fatjar with the required lib: 1) Add folder lib/ to root folder of your project 2) Folder lib/ should contain all the extra .jars 3) Create a package for your project (.jar)

Comment: Fatjar was first thing I did. That works fine. Now I am trying to refine and seperate those jars and use the mechanism provided by Hadoop and that (libjars) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the command using the fully qualified absolute file name for the external.jar.  Also confirm that the missing class and all of its prerequisite classes are in the external.jar.

Comment: I am using fully qualified absolute file name and all classes in the jar file.

Comment: Hi Chris! I have a question on MapReduce, Hadoop and JAR files that I would really like you to take a look at and let me know your thoughts. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026170/using-hadoop-to-run-a-jar-file-python. Please do take a look. 

OP: I'm really sorry to be hijacking, but I am in dire need of help. My sincerest apologies.