# Using Hadoop to run a jar file - Python

Tags: python, hadoop, jar, mapreduce, hdfs

I have an existing Python program that has a sequence of operations that goes something like this:

1. Connect to MySQL DB and retrieve files into local FS.
2. Run a program X that operates on these files. Something like: `java -jar X.jar <folder_name>` This will open every file in the folder and perform some operation on them and writes out an equal number of transformed files into another folder.
3. Then, run a program Y that operates on *these* files as: `java -jar Y.jar <folder_name>` This creates multiple files of one line each which are then merged into a single file using a merge function.
4. This merged file is then the input for some further operations and analyses that is not really important for this question.

I'd like to use make use of Hadoop to speed up operation Y as it takes very long to complete if there are: a) more number of files or b) large input files to be operated upon.

What I'd like to know is if it is a good idea to go with Hadoop in the first place to do something of this nature and if threads would make more sense in this case. Bear in mind that X and Y are things that **cannot** be replaced or changed in any way.

I came up with this idea:

1. After step 2 above, within a mapper, copy the files into the HDFS and back out again, run the jar file, at which point the results are written back into the HDFS. I copy the results back out to the File System and send it for further processing.

I would like to know if this makes sense at all and especially given that the mapper expects a (key,value) pair, would I even have a k-v pair in this scenario?

I know this sounds like a project and that's because it is, but I'm not looking for code, just some guidance about whether or not this would even work and if it did, what is the right way of going about doing this if my proposed solution is not accurate (enough).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can use hadoop mapreduce framework to complete your work, but the answer for if it's a good idea could be "it depends". It depends the number and sizes of files you want to proceed.

Keep in mind that hdfs is not very good at deal with small files, it could be a disaster for the namenode if you have a good number (say 10 million) of small files (size is less than 1k bytes). An another hand, if the sizes are too large but only a few files are needed to proceed, it is not cool to just wrap step#2 directly in a mapper, because the job won't be spread widely and evenly (in this situation i guess the key-value only can be "file no. - file content" or "file name - file content" given you mentioned X can't changed in any way. Actually, "line no. - line" would be more situable)

BTW, there are 2 ways to utilize hadoop mapreduce framework, one way is you write mapper/reducer in java and compile them in jar then run mapreduce job with hadoop jar you_job.jar . Another way is [streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/cn/streaming.html), you can write mapper/reducer by using python is this way.

Comment: I'd say that the files are about 1MB max with about 300-500 files at best that need to be processed. The process of applying Y on each of these files is slow, ie, while the file opening and closing may be fast, the operation that it does on the files depends entirely on the size of the file. Smaller files take shorter time and larger files take more time. However, the files in terms of size are relatively small.Its the operation that Y performs that takes a long time and that's what we'd like to cut down. Also, if you know of an article/tutorial that shows how to run a jar file within a mapper

Comment: it would be great. Also, can you please clarify your key-value pair and what exactly you mean by it? I'm just a little lost and confused. Sorry!

Comment: did you intend to create a mapper for step#3? i thought you wanted treat step#2 as a mapper and step#3 as a reducer, which makes more sense to me. I guess you can easily run a jar within a mapper by calling the java command line. As for the key-value, i think it would be better to pass in each line of a file in mapper, anyway, passing in each file would also work based on your file size is small.

Comment: Well, the eventual plan is to put both step 2 and step 3 into their own mappers and reducers, but I'm taking it slow and if I can get step 3 to successfully execute within a mapper and/or reducer, I can replicate that for step 2 as well. The problem with passing it line by line is that Y.jar needs the whole file and not individual lines. It reads the file line by line, analyses it and writes out a single line descriptor for the whole file. Even if we went with step 2 as mapper and step 3 as reducer, the same problem persists. How to run a jar file which depends on the OS and system environment

Comment: inside of Hadoop, which is almost like a layer of isolation between the OS and its own HDFS? That's the part that is the most unclear and specifically, the code - what would that look like inside the mapper? Currently, the way it executes is ` os.system(cmd_line)` where `cmd_line` represents something like: `java -jar /path/to/jar/Y.jar -args folder_name`. How would this change when writing a map job?

Comment: usually, the files on HDFS will be stored on data nodes (you can specify the location in the spec file), while you do file operation on name node by using "hadoop fs" commands, the isolation could be different machines in the hadoop cluster if i understand that question correctly. Again, the Y.jar will be on name node local file system instead of HDFS as well, so you can execute the jar as what you did before.

Comment: Ultimately, the files you want to proceed will be on HDFS, then you will have a mapreduce job (say job.jar) and Y.jar on name node local file system. The you start the job with "hadoop jar job.jar" and the in job.jar you call Y.jar with 'java -jar /path/to/jar/Y.jar'

Comment: And Hadoop would be able to access the jar file with no issues? Again.. how would I be able to chart out the key-value pairs? As such, the key would be the folder name and the value would be the files upon which the jar file performs its operations. Would that work? I apologize for asking so many questions.. I'm just very unclear on the exact flow of events.

Comment: hadoop shouldn't have any problem to access the jar file on local disk. The key could be the folder name and value could be the files under that folder. Again, the performance could depend on the way how folders/files are distributed. It won't worth if all the files are located in a single folder. Why can't you just modify the X.jar and Y.jar to make them more suitable for the mapreduce jobs? It could be even better to simulate what X.jar and Y.jar do in your mapper and reducer.

Comment: I would do that, but X and Y are application packages that run as jar files. Changing those would mean rewriting the entire application in MapReduce!

Comment: right, but it's also a good chance to get familiar with hadoop, isn't it :P I would suggest to try to start with playing around with hadoop before you make your decision

Comment: I'm okay-familiar with it, but unfortunately, we're under some constraints and cannot really do it at this point of time. But I'll try your approach. Can I email you, if possible to consult you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41448/discussion-between-codingincircles-and-zhutoulala)